# Trying to fix the size of part{} font in the toc

Tags: table-of-contents, titlesec

I am having some trouble when using `\part{\Huge Literature review and State of the art }` in my thesis. Check this out:

[image]

This one look fine since it is a single page in the document and the font size is correct. The problem is in the table of contents. Check this out:

[image]

It is way too big. How can I fix this issue? I tried by replacing `\titleformat*{\part}{\LARGE\bfseries}` in the MWE but it throws an error.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat*{\section}{\LARGE\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\Large\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\large\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\paragraph}{\large\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\subparagraph}{\large\bfseries}

\begin{document}

\section{Test section}
\subsection{Test section}
\subsubsection{Test section}
\paragraph{Test section}
\subparagraph{Test section}

\end{document}
```

> Here is an example where it works fine:

[image]
[image]

These are my packages:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                    
\usepackage[english,spanish]{babel}         
\usepackage{graphicx}                        
\usepackage{amsthm, amsmath, amssymb}       
\usepackage{setspace}\onehalfspacing        
\usepackage[loose,nice]{units}              
\usepackage{titlepage}               
\usepackage{indentfirst}                    
\usepackage{lipsum}                         
\usepackage{aas_macros}                     
\usepackage{hyperref}                       
\usepackage{bookmark}                       
\usepackage{fancyhdr}                       
\usepackage{emptypage}                      
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}            
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\normalfont}
\graphicspath{{./figures/}}                 
\usepackage[Sonny]{fncychap}                
\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}         

\geometry{bindingoffset=1cm}                
\geometry{textwidth=390pt}                  
\addto\captionsspanish{\renewcommand{\listtablename}{Índice de tablas}}
```

This is my main.tex:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside,openright]{book}
\input{packages}



\begin{document}


%
% Frontmatter
    \frontmatter
%   Titlepage
    \maketitle
%   Dedication
    \input{dedicacion}

    \input{summary}
%   
    \input{aknwole}

    \input{tableofcontents}
    \listoffigures
    \listoftables
% Mainmatter
    \mainmatter

    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \input{intro}
    \input{chap1}
    \input{chap2}
    \input{chap3}
    \input{results}
    \appendix
    \input{apendixA}
    \input{apendixB}
% Backmatter
    \backmatter
    \input{biblio}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please edit your code example so that it actually reproduces the screenshot(s) you've posted. The reason for making this request is that (a) you would appear to load other packages as well -- `babel` with the option `french`, right?; `geometry`? `tocloft` -- and (b) these packages and the document class (not really `article`, right?) might interact with `titlesec`. Hence, it's important to know what the actual code is.

Comment: @Mico Hello Mico. It is not `article`, but rather a `book` document. `babel` with the option french, spanish and englsh. Package `geometry` is loaded so is `tocloft`

Comment: @Mico I have  `\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}` like that. `\usepackage{tocloft}` and also  `\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\normalfont}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You observe that

> I am having some trouble when using `\part{\Huge Literature review and State of the art }`

For sure, don't ever include fontsize-related directives in the body of a sectioning command.

I take it that you want the numbering part of the `part`-level header -- say, "Première Partie" -- to have the font size, *viz.*, `\Huge` as the body of the `part`-level header -- say, "Projet PEUGEOT: Méthode de dopage". (For the `book` document class, the default font size for the numbering part is `\huge`, not `\Huge`.) If this is the case, you may achieve your formatting objective by (a) not loading the `titlesec` package and not employing `\titesec*` instructions and (b) loading the `sectsty` package and employing `\partfont`, `\chapterfont`, etc directives:

```
\usepackage{sectsty}
\partfont{\Huge}
\chapterfont{\huge}
\sectionfont{\LARGE}
\subsectionfont{\Large}
\subsubsectionfont{\large}
\paragraphfont{\large}    
\subparagraphfont{\large}
```

Incidentally, I don't think it's advisable to set the font size of `paragraph` and `subparagraph` headers to `\large`; doing so creates a bad visual clash with the subsequent material, which will be typeset in `\normalsize`.

---

A full MWE and its output (I've added the `french` language option to make the output conform better to the screenshots you posted):

[image]

---

[image]

---

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\usepackage[english,spanish,french]{babel}
\addto\captionsspanish{\renewcommand{\listtablename}{Índice de tablas}}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\normalfont}
\usepackage{lipsum}   % filler text

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[Sonny]{fncychap}

%\usepackage{titlesec}
%%\titleformat*{\part}{\LARGE\bfseries}
%\titleformat*{\section}{\LARGE\bfseries}
%\titleformat*{\subsection}{\Large\bfseries}
%\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\large\bfseries}
%\titleformat*{\paragraph}{\large\bfseries}
%\titleformat*{\subparagraph}{\large\bfseries}

\usepackage{sectsty}
\partfont{\Huge}
\chapterfont{\huge}
\sectionfont{\LARGE}
\subsectionfont{\Large}
\subsubsectionfont{\large}
\paragraphfont{\large}    
\subparagraphfont{\large} 

%% load the hyperref package last:
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\part{Projet PEUGEOT: Méthode de dopage pour la détection et classification de véhicules}

\chapter*{Introduction}
\chapter{Détection de véhicules: \'Etat de l'art}

\section{Test section}
\subsection{Test subsection}
\subsubsection{Test subsubsection}

\paragraph{Test paragraph}
\lipsum[2]

\subparagraph{Test subparagraph}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Beyond expected! Thank you so much. There’s so many tricks in this TeX that if it wasn’t for this website i’d be having a bad time.