# Adding more space between & and lines

Tags: table-of-contents, titlesec

How can I add more space between the **&** and the two lines?

Credits to [Mico](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/514591/194319) for the amazing MWE.

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\usepackage[english,spanish,french]{babel}
\addto\captionsspanish{\renewcommand{\listtablename}{Índice de tablas}}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\normalfont}
\usepackage{lipsum}   % filler text

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[Sonny]{fncychap}

%\usepackage{titlesec}
%%\titleformat*{\part}{\LARGE\bfseries}
%\titleformat*{\section}{\LARGE\bfseries}
%\titleformat*{\subsection}{\Large\bfseries}
%\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\large\bfseries}
%\titleformat*{\paragraph}{\large\bfseries}
%\titleformat*{\subparagraph}{\large\bfseries}

\usepackage{sectsty}
\partfont{\Huge}
\chapterfont{\huge}
\sectionfont{\LARGE}
\subsectionfont{\Large}
\subsubsectionfont{\large}
\paragraphfont{\large}    
\subparagraphfont{\large} 

%% load the hyperref package last:
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\part{Theoretical background \\ \& \\ state of the art}

\chapter*{Introduction}
\chapter{Détection de véhicules: \'Etat de l'art}

\section{Test section}
\subsection{Test subsection}
\subsubsection{Test subsubsection}

\paragraph{Test paragraph}
\lipsum[2]

\subparagraph{Test subparagraph}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Adding a default header `\documentclass{book}\usepackage{sectsty}\usepackage{lipsum}`, I can't reproduce the issue. You must have something more than that. Are you perhaps using both `sectsty` and `titlesec`? That's a “no-no”.

Comment: @egreg Check it now. I forgot a part.

Comment: No issue with the new MWE. By the way, the default language for the picture seems to be Spanish, rather than French, which would print “Seconde partie” instead of “Parte II”.

Comment: Never mind about the language. All I care about is the spacing!

Comment: As I said, with the very same MWE, I get [this result (click)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WBQ4Z.png)

Comment: @egreg Have you checked what happens to the table of contents? The double `\\` has an impact there.

Comment: You weren't asking for the table of contents, were you? The line spacing in the TOC is as expected. Solve *that* issue by ``\part[Theoretical background \& state of the art]{Theoretical background \\ \& \\ state of the art}``. I'd not use `\&` in this case even under threat for life, though.

Comment: Your workaround did work and, no, I was not asking for `toc` but it is implicit. We assume that If we do something like that it'll have an impact in the `toc`. Could you please explain why you do not use `\&` in this case?

Comment: `\&` is good for firms and commercial products. Some bibliography styles (APA, for instance) mandate it for citations. My opinion is that it has no place in a book, except for reporting names that already have it (“I went to buy groceries at Smith & Sons'”). Nevertheless, until you show a short document that produces the bad spacing, I can't help more.

Comment: You have a good point. Though I had seen it in a PhD thesis so I though It would be okay if I use it as well.

Comment: @egreg I have the feeling that this line `\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.1} `before `\begin{document}` in my Tex thesis document  might be the responsible for what's going on.

Comment: @egreg I nice idea would be using `\textit{\&}` instead of `\$` :)